# How to add a TextView on top of Application Icon in Android

Tags: android

Hi any idea about how to add a TextView on top of application icon.Because i want to add a number(say 50 by default)and the number may vary dynamically.So far i have used only icon and label attributes to the application tag  in manifest file.Any idea about this.Thanks in advance.

Thanks&Regards,
Venakat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile your app, it compiles with 1 icon per resolution, and that icon cannot be changed unless you release an update. it can't be dynamically changed after compiling.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.I agree with you.